# How to parse nls fit (multi line text) file using r?

Tags: r

How to parse nls fit (multi line text) file as given below using r?

```
Nonlinear regression model
  model: A ~ BOTTOM + (TOP - BOTTOM)/(1 + 10^((logEC50 - xdata) * hillSlope))
   data: keep
      TOP    BOTTOM hillSlope   logEC50 
  101.027     0.704     1.374    -6.319 
 residual sum-of-squares: 581.7

Number of iterations to convergence: 7 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.798e-06
```

I would like to get a table of fourth row text as column headers and the fifth row numbers as values s shown below:

```
TOP      BOTTOM   hillSlope   logEC50 
101.027  0.704    1.374       -6.319
```

Comment: See `help("coef")` for extracting coefficients directly from the model object.

Comment: coef(fit) worked like a charm. Thank you for directing me to coef() function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these three parameters, *skip/nrows/header* with `read.table`:

```
read.table(text = "Nonlinear regression model
    model: A ~ BOTTOM + (TOP - BOTTOM)/(1 + 10^((logEC50 - xdata) * hillSlope))
     data: keep
        TOP    BOTTOM hillSlope   logEC50 
    101.027     0.704     1.374    -6.319 
   residual sum-of-squares: 581.7

  Number of iterations to convergence: 7 
  Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.798e-06", skip = 3, nrows = 1, header = T)

#      TOP BOTTOM hillSlope logEC50
#1 101.027  0.704     1.374  -6.319
```

As per @42- required:

- Use `skip` to specify how many rows you want to ignore when reading in;
- Specify `header = T` so the first row after skipping the rows will be read as headers;
- Then you only want to read in one more row as the body, use `nrows = 1` to specify this;

Comment: OK. Explain what happens here. That text did not look like it should have gotten parsed.

Comment: @42- I thought these parameters are self explanatory, but I added the explanation to make it clearer.

Comment: Thank you pointing out that there was code (parameter list) after the text. My wetware was not parsing it correctly.